# Enable/Disable Android ActionBar.Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm developing an application that uses the new Tabs system (ActionBar.addTab()), I will have 3 tabs.
During a determined process I would like to lock (disable) two of them (not remove, only do not accept clicks and not change the 'selector'.

I was able to do not change the content (by implementing the TabListener and not changing the fragment, etc) but the selector changes.

Is there anyway to only disable/enable the tabs? without have to remove and add again?

Thanks in advance!
BR,
Danilo

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, there is no "enable" or "disable" with tabs in the action bar. As you note, you can remove and re-add them -- that is the closest you can get AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I see! Thanks. I've manager to add a bizarre behavior by adding a check on the TabListener, if I "can" change the tabs I change, if not I re-select the latest tab =P

Comment: @DaniloBertelli Your workaround isn't that straightforward. For it to update the selected tab View properly your "reselect the latest tab" will need to be in a Runnable queued via a post on one of the views. If you really want to know why then look in ScrollingTabContainerView#TabClickListener.onClick - as your tab.select call will need to be after the call to [child.setSelected](http://is.gd/OCa2tF) in that method.

Comment: @Daniel there are not enough characters in this input box to express my thanks. Basically I'm already using a `Handler` for various async tasks in my `Activity`, I simply put `setSelectedNavigationItem()` as a new ``Runnable`` with ``postAtFrontOfQueue()`` there. Brilliant!

Comment: I'm with Foxx1337, this was an incredibly helpful comment, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got into the exact same issue. Finally was able to solve it. As said already, there is no way to disable/enable a tab. There is only one way out - and that is to go back to the previous tab using

```
getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(tab);
```

Note however, that this should **NOT** be done from within the

```
onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
```

method, because then it gets stuck in recursive loop. So within the onTabSelected() - send a messsage to the Activity Handler to do the setSelectedNavigation().

One catch here is (you will know when you implement): what "tab" value to pass in the setSelectedNavigation. For this, we have to keep track of whether it is a user pressed tab switch or forced switch to the last tab via the code.

For this:

```
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    if (forcedTabSwitch)
        forcedTabSwitch = false;
    else 
        mTabToBeSwitchedTo = tab.getPosition();
}
```

and in the Handler,

```
switch (msg.what) {
            case SWITCH_TO_TAB :
                forcedTabSwitch = true;
                            break;
}
```

Comment: Hi, for me getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position) not working. What may be issue, I am trying to set the position of the tab on some conditions. Can someone help me..

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem.My application has three tabs and each tab has buttons to move onto next and previous tab.
I don't find any method for  enabling or disabling tab.

I used DataSetter class to hold previously selected tab position and boolean value to determine tab selection.
If boolean flag is true then user has pressed next/previous button. Otherwise user is trying to select tab by pressing 
them which we don't allow.
I used handler for tab selection.Inside fragment when user clicks next button I broadcast that request.
Broadcast request has integer parameter which is position of next or previous tab that we want to set.
Code inside fragment is:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_tab_fragment, container, false); 
      next = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
      next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent("TAB_CLICKED");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(MainActivity.POSITION,1);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
     });
    return rootView;
    }
```

I have used CustomViewPager instead of ViewPager to prevent tab swiping.
CustomViewPager class is :

```
            public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {            

            private boolean enabled;            
            public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (this.enabled) {
                    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if (this.enabled) {
                        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
                    }

                    return false;
            }

            public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
                this.enabled = enabled;
            }             
        }
```

Inside oncreate method of MainActivity.java add this two lines:

```
     viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
     viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
```

Below is remaining code from MainActivity.java:

```
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    Log.d("MainActivity","onTabSelected");  
    if(setter.getFlag() == true)
    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(setter.getposition());
    }           
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("MainActivity","onTabUnselected");    
    //handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    Message message = new Message();
    message.arg1 = setter.getposition();
    handler.sendMessage(message);       
}

Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
    {
        int arg1 = msg.arg1;            
        Log.d("arg1",arg1+"");
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(arg1);
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg1);
        Log.d("handler","Inside handler");
    }
};

BroadcastReceiver receiver =  new BroadcastReceiver(){

    public void onReceive(Context context, android.content.Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int position = bundle.getInt(MainActivity.POSITION);
        Log.d("Action",action);
        Log.d("position",position+"");
        setter.setposition(position);
        setter.setflag(true);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.arg1 = position;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    };
   };
 }
```

Finally DataSetter.java :

```
    public class DataSetter 
    {
        int position;
        boolean flag;   
        void setposition(int value)
        {
            position = value;
        }   
        void setflag(boolean value)
        {
            flag = value;
        }   
        int getposition()
        {
            return position;
        }   
        boolean getFlag()
        {
            return flag;
        }
    }
```

More you can find on: http://suhas1989.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/enable-or-disable-actionbar-tab-in-android/